# Writing a matrix to text file using write() function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a function to write a matrix to a text file but it's not displaying anything on the text file.

```
def writeFile1(self, filename, matrix):
        openFile = open(filename, 'w')

        for row in matrix:
            row_str = " ".join(str(x) for x in row) #convert row to string
            print(row_str)
            openFile.write(row_str + "\n")
            
        openFile.close()
```

I am not able to figure out the problem.Please help
NOTE - please don't use numpy

- I have created this method inside a class , that deals with matrix-file I/O
- This function intends to write a provided matrix to a provided file
- But the text file is still blank after running the program

Comment: most probably the matrix is empty

Comment: does the `print(row_str)` line do what you expect ?

Comment: You could try `open(FileName, 'w+')`. This can fix an error if you don't have enough privileges to edit a file.

Comment: Side note: It looks like this should be a `staticmethod`/`classmethod`?

Comment: Thanks to @Caridorc for pointing out the mistake, it was due to the empty matrix